# pwa not installable

Tags: javascript, https, progressive-web-apps

I am developping a pwa following this tutorial
https://medium.com/james-johnson/a-simple-progressive-web-app-tutorial-f9708e5f2605

my app has the following structure

index.html

manifest.webmanifest

style.css

main.js

service-worker.js

icone-144.png

icone-192.png

icone-512.png

it is hosted on an https site. my browser supports the service worker.

when i connect to my app via my phone, the "add to screen" banner don't appears. i can install the firefox demo app:
https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/

what is missing to make my app installable ?
are there alternatives to a2hs ?

Answer (score 1):

I understood the many reasons that prevented my app from working:

the ssl was not yet activated on my site ^o^

the service-worker code contained a lot of errors

i had difficulties to understand which urls should be written in the manifest and the cache's file list

Comment: don't forget to mark this answer as solved